# Aptana 3: How to set PHP to execute a php file as a script?

Tags: php, eclipse, ide, aptana, aptana3

I am very new in PHP world and now I have install Apatana 3 Studio and I have some question to you about PHP configuration in this development environment.

Seems that my configuration work well but I don't know if it is configured in a smart way...

I use Ubuntu and I have installed Apache 2 web server

Executing a simple php file (that is inside my /var/www folder) conteining phpinfo() functiion:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

I obtain some information and seems that I have installed Apache 2 web server under this path: /etc/php5/apache2 and that the php.ini file have this path: /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

Infact, this is part of the phpinfo() output that I obtain:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /etc/php5/apache2
Loaded Configuration File   /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

As web server I use an external version of Apache+PHP and it work well. My doubt is related to the execution of a PHP file as a script (not on a web server):

If I select a PHP file inside a project and I do: Run As --> PHP Script appear to me an error message that say me that I have to set the PHP executable location and open a wizard to do it.

So now I am under: Preferences ---> Aptana Studio ---> PHP ---> PHP Interpretes and this is void.

So I have do the following operations: click on add button and set the following values in the wizard:

> ```
> Name: PHP
>
> Executable Path: /usr/bin/php5 (php5 is the executable file, I don't know if this setting is right)
>
> PHP ini file: /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini (I have obtained this path from the phpinfo() function)
>
> PHPDebbugger: XDebug (setting by default)
> ```

So I click Finish and give me the following error message: Error saving /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

Why? maybe I have no writing permission on this file?

But now, if I try to execute my php file as a script seems work well and I obtain the desidered output inside the Console tab

This configuration is it right or not?